# Navigating to a new route doesn't load component data in Angular

Tags: angular, routes, components, router, routerlink

I am rendering an Angular component in order to display data based on the entity's `id`

```
<a *ngFor="let detail of details" [routerLink]="['/record-details', detail.id">
  Go to page {{detail.name}}
</a>
```

**record-details.component.ts**

```
public id;
public issueDetails;

constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private recordDetailsService: RecordDetailsService,
) {
    route.params.subscribe(params => this.id = params.id);

}

async ngOnInit() {
    await this.getDetails(this.id);
}

async getDetails(id) {
    try {
      this.issueDetails = await this.recordDetailsService.getDetails(id);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
}
```

But whenever I click on the html link to go to a new page, it only changes the route parameter. I'd like to load data based on the new `id` as well

What am I doing wrong?

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
{
    path: 'record-details',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./record-details/record-details.module').then(m => m.RecordDetailsModule)
},
```

**record-details-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: RecordDetailsComponent
  }
];
```

Comment: can you show the code where you define the route?

Comment: @Alexander check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

What jumps out to me when looking at the code is why are using async and await.  With angular, I would lean into using observables.

```
public id;
public issueDetails;

constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private recordDetailsService: RecordDetailsService,
) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.id = route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.getDetails(this.id);
}

getDetails(id) {
    this.recordDetailsService.getDetails(id).subscribe(issueDetails => {
        this.issueDetails = issueDetails;
    }, error => console.error(error));
}
```

You also need to change your recordDetailsService to be an observable

Comment: I switched back to the observables but it still doesn't update the component data

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work, check [hero-detail component](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/router/stackblitz)